# Get related fields of max value when grouping in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

What would be the corresponding mongo query for below SQL that gets the `lat` and `long` of the most recent doc for each `did`:

Query : what is the last location for all devices

```
did  : device id
ts   : time stamp
lat  : latitude 
long : longitude
```

**SQL Query**

```
  SELECT 
        did , ts, `lat`, `long`
    FROM
        points
            JOIN
        (SELECT 
            MAX(ts) AS maxTs, did
        FROM
            points
        GROUP BY did) MxData ON points.ts = MxData.maxTs
            AND MxData.did = points.did;
```

Below is the Mongo Query, I am able to get max time stamp for device but not sure how to print the corresponding lat and long

```
db.points.aggregate( [{ $group:{_id: "$did", maxTs: { $max: "$ts" }}}]).pretty();
```

Comment: Your schema is normalized I think while it should not be in case of mongo.

Comment: Everything is in one document it is not normalized

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution , the query is

```
db.points.aggregate([
    {$sort:{"ts":1}} , 
    {$group:{"_id":"$did" , result:{$last:"$ts"}  , lat:{$last:"$lat"} , lon:{$last:"$lon"}}}
    ]);
```